# display the value of a hidden input

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

i am using jquery ui date picker for users to pick the date when they pick the date i have a hidden field which adds the value of the date picker in a alternate date format.

what i need to do is dynamically output the value of the hidden input.

i have tried this but it only seems to work if the user types in the date manually and doesn't use the date picker image icons and scroll through the calendar.

```
$('#datepicker').keyup(function () {
$('#date-output').text($(this).val());
});
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

**Jquery date picker code**

```
//date pickers
$(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
        showOn: "button",
        buttonImage: "images/calendar.gif",
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        dateFormat:"dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: +0,
        altField: "#alternate",
        altFormat: "D MM d",
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
        var suffix = "";
        switch(inst.selectedDay) {
            case '1': case '21': case '31': suffix = 'st'; break;
            case '2': case '22': suffix = 'nd'; break;
            case '3': case '23': suffix = 'rd'; break;
            default: suffix = 'th';
        }

    $("#alternate").val($("#alternate").val() + suffix);
}
        });
    });
```

**HTML**

```
<input name="datepicker" class="calendarInput" type="text" id="datepicker">
<input name="alternate" id="alternate" type="hidden" >
<span id="date-output"></span>
```

Comment: can you please make a jsfiddle

Comment: here you go http://jsfiddle.net/UqJtG/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/Ucun7/)

```
 onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
    var suffix = "";
    switch(inst.selectedDay) {
        case '1': case '21': case '31': suffix = 'st'; break;
        case '2': case '22': suffix = 'nd'; break;
        case '3': case '23': suffix = 'rd'; break;
        default: suffix = 'th';
    }

    var val = $("#alternate").val() + suffix;
    $("#alternate").val(val);
    $('#date-output').text(val);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use onSelect API method

http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-onSelect

Answer (score 0):

you can use `onSelect` event

```
$(function() {
    $("#datepicker").datepicker({
        dateFormat: "dd/mm/yy",
        minDate: +0,
        altField: "#alternate",
        altFormat: "D MM d",
        onSelect: function(dateText, inst) {
            debugger
            var suffix = "";
            switch (inst.selectedDay) {
            case '1':
            case '21':
            case '31':
                suffix = 'st';
                break;
            case '2':
            case '22':
                suffix = 'nd';
                break;
            case '3':
            case '23':
                suffix = 'rd';
                break;
            default:
                suffix = 'th';
            }

            $("#alternate").val($("#alternate").val() + suffix);
            $('#date-output').text($(this).val());
        }
    });
});​
```

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/UqJtG/1/)